# Does replacing an audio device's AC adapter with a 9v battery require filtering?

Tags: power-supply, batteries

I have two devices that use 'wall wart' adapters - an audio mixer and an audio headphone amplifier. Each is 120vac input and 9vdc output. I'm a technician so understand how to check for proper voltage, current and polarity for each device. But is there a way that I can determine if my devices require some degree of filtering or steady delivery that a 9v or 12v battery as a substitute wouldn't be able to provide? For ex. - for a laptop computer to perform well, it may need a very stable power supply free of spikes or other small aberrations.

Comment: Other way round, usually. When replacing batteries with an AC source, you often need filtering to suppress AC ripple. One case where a battery will be a problem would be an analog synthesiser, which would probably drift out of tune as the battery flattened.

Comment: If your device requires a steady input, you'll need a voltage regulator as a 9V battery is really more of a ~7V to ~9V battery.  There are a variety of 9V batteries, but if you're considering the standard box type, you may want to consider a AAA or AA battery pack with the same voltage instead.  The little 9V box batteries are only good for low current and cost a lot more per unit charge so they're best used only for very low draw devices that require a small package.

Comment: K H  - Actually, this was at the root of my question - how can I determine if my device requires a steady input or other design requirement that a battery just can't deliver. I suppose it would require looking at each device's circuit at the engineering level.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that from the point of view of noise, spikes, and in general EMI, batteries are a bless, because they look like the ideal DC source. They have an internal resistance that is quite low, so they can even provide current even in case of a pulsed peaky current request.
They have also some stray capacitance so in some way they are already a "filter".
They are also insulated from ground and can avoid much of the common mode disturbance. Of course a large battery has some stray capacitance to ground, but it is not your case, probably; if so, you can prop up on spacers and separate from earthed parts and ground potential.

What they don't do is providing a stabilized output:

- if there is a significant current absorption, you will see a corresponding voltage reduction due to the internal voltage drop;
- with use, when the charge reduces, the voltage is also somewhat reduced, following the known discharge curve typical of each type of battery (e.g. LiIon, NiCd, NiMH, etc.)
- when you connect a charger and you keep everything connected (so you are still supplying your device), be careful that the voltage is higher and may be above the rating of the connected device.